# useminPrepare options property not defined

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, jshint, grunt-usemin

I'm getting a jshint error when I run `grunt` from the command line.

```
    Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
    Going through public/index.html to update the config
    Looking for build script HTML comment blocks
    Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'options' of undefined). Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

In my gruntfile I have:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }
},
```

And yeoman.dist is defined in grunt.initConfig:

```
yeoman: {
  // configurable paths
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'public',
  dist: 'dist'
},
```

Why am I getting the Cannot read property 'options' of undefined error?

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. I had another task configured wrong in the gruntfile. 
I reused a task from another project that didn't have the object defined.

From another project I had:

`<%= yeoman.dist %>`

which was not defined in this project.

I found it by running grunt with `--debug --verbose --force` to see what else broke. The task that breaks likely has the mistake.